# How do I play Monaco with friends?

Tags: steam, monaco

I see no obvious way to play Monaco with friends, but surely that must be an available option in a coop game that uses Steamworks?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a bit of a pain. From the main menu:

1. Select Play Monaco
2. Pick the mission
3. Make sure "Play online" is selected, fix with P if necessary.
4. Select "Custom match" with X
5. Select "Create match" with X
6. Make it private, confirm with SPACE or ENTER. If you create a public game, the lobby system will quickly dump people in your game and you won't be able to add friends :(
7. Pick your class, confirm with SPACE or ENTER
8. Select custom options with X
9. Hit Invite Friends with SPACE or ENTER
10. Do your inviting.

Done! From the same menu you can change the mission, if you want to.